# Upgraded 14.04 LTS to 16.04, cannot login as splash-screen just keeps looping and no login possible

Tags: 16.04

I am using Dell M6800 with one SSD, and one HDD, and an AMD Firepro card.
2. The do-release-upgrade -d went through without any problems but I never get the GUI login prompt, the splash screen with Ubuntu and dots just loops for ever. ctrl-alt-f1 does not get a command prompt, nor does ctrl-alt-f7 give the gui login. I had selected gdm3 as the default display manager, as I have always used gdm. In my SSD I have Ubuntu 14.04 (which is running just fine, and currently logged into it).
3. I can go to recovery mode though, but so far I could not get it to work, and have tried the usual suggestion on the ubuntu site for this problem.
4. I do notice that there is no resolv.conf, and if I create one, it get written over to a null file on reboot. I am not using the AMD Firepro Graphics right now. I can download and enable the Intel graphics driver or the AMD Firepro driver if these would help. Currently, no NVidia or Nouveau module are in the kernel.

Please Please advise urgently...
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading to 16.04.1, I had selected gdm3, instead of gdm, this was the root cause. Used root shell in recovery mode, and installed gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome-desktop and gnome-session. rebooted and can now GUI is back and very pleasing in 16.04.1. I use metacity gnome option...Regards